# Attempting to grab certain Elements

Tags: python, html, xpath

I am new to lxml module in Python. 
I am trying to parse data from a website: https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USCA1037:1:US

I am trying to grab the text of :

```
<span classname="narrative" class="narrative">
  Cloudy. Low 49F. Winds WNW at 10 to 20 mph.
</span>
```

However, I am getting my xpath all mixed up.

To be exact, the location of this line is

```
//*[@id="twc-scrollabe"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/span
```

I've attempted as the following

```
import requests

import lxml.html

from lxml import etree



html = requests.get("https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USCA1037:1:US")

element_object = lxml.html.fromstring(html.content)  # htmlelement object returns bytes
  # element_object has root of <html>

table = element_object.xpath('//div[@class="twc-table-scroller"]')[0]
day_of_week = table.xpath('.//span[@class="date-time"]/text()')  # returns list of items from "dates-time"
dates = table.xpath('.//span[@class="day-detail clearfix"]/text()')

td = table.xpath('.//tbody/tr/td/span[contains(@class, "narrative")]')
print td

  # print td displays an empty list.
```

I would like my program to also parse "Cloudy. Low 49F. Winds WNW at 10 to 20 mph."

Please help...

Comment: this line is in many `<td>`, not in one <span>. `<td><span>Cloudy.</span></td><td><span>Low 49F.</span></td>` etc.

Comment: web browser may show `<tbody>` in DevTool but this tag may not exist in HTML file - so better skip  `<tbody>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some `<td>` have `title=` with description

```
import requests
import lxml.html

html = requests.get("https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USCA1037:1:US")

element_object = lxml.html.fromstring(html.content)
table = element_object.xpath('//div[@class="twc-table-scroller"]')[0]

td = table.xpath('.//tr/td[@class="twc-sticky-col"]/@title')
print(td)
```

Result

```
['Mostly cloudy skies early, then partly cloudy after midnight. Low 48F. Winds SSW at 5 to 10 mph.', 
 'Mainly sunny. High 66F. Winds WNW at 5 to 10 mph.', 
 'Sunny. High 71F. Winds NW at 5 to 10 mph.', 
 'A mainly sunny sky. High 69F. Winds W at 5 to 10 mph.', 
 'Some clouds in the morning will give way to mainly sunny skies for the afternoon. High 67F. Winds WSW at 5 to 10 mph.', 
 'Considerable clouds early. Some decrease in clouds later in the day. High 67F. Winds WSW at 5 to 10 mph.', 
 'Partly cloudy. High near 65F. Winds WSW at 5 to 10 mph.', 
 'Cloudy skies early, then partly cloudy in the afternoon. High 61F. Winds WSW at 10 to 20 mph.', 
 'Sunny skies. High 62F. Winds WNW at 10 to 20 mph.', 
 'Mainly sunny. High 61F. Winds WNW at 10 to 20 mph.', 
 'Sunny along with a few clouds. High 64F. Winds WNW at 10 to 15 mph.', 
 'Mostly sunny skies. High around 65F. Winds WNW at 10 to 15 mph.', 
 'Mostly sunny skies. High 66F. Winds WNW at 10 to 20 mph.', 
 'Mainly sunny. High around 65F. Winds WNW at 10 to 20 mph.', 
 'A mainly sunny sky. High around 65F. Winds WNW at 10 to 20 mph.']
```

There is no `<tbody>` in HTML but web browser may display it in DevTool - so don't use `tbody` in xpath.

Some text is in `<span></span>` but some in `<span><span></span></span>`

```
import requests
import lxml.html

html = requests.get("https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/USCA1037:1:US")

element_object = lxml.html.fromstring(html.content)
table = element_object.xpath('//div[@class="twc-table-scroller"]')[0]

td = table.xpath('.//tr/td//span/text()')
print(td)
```

Result

```
['Tonight', 'APR 21', 'Partly Cloudy', '--', '48', '10', '%', 'SSW 7 mph ', '85', '%', 
 'Mon', 'APR 22', 'Sunny', '66', '51', '10', '%', 'WNW 9 mph ', '67', '%', 
 'Tue', 'APR 23', 'Sunny', '71', '53', '0', '%', 'NW 8 mph ', '59', '%', 
 'Wed', 'APR 24', 'Sunny', '69', '52', '10', '%', 'W 9 mph ', '71', '%', 
 'Thu', 'APR 25', 'Partly Cloudy', '67', '51', '10', '%', 'WSW 9 mph ', '71', '%', 
 'Fri', 'APR 26', 'Partly Cloudy', '67', '51', '10', '%', 'WSW 9 mph ', '69', '%', 
 'Sat', 'APR 27', 'Partly Cloudy', '65', '50', '10', '%', 'WSW 9 mph ', '71', '%',   
 'Sun', 'APR 28', 'AM Clouds/PM Sun', '61', '49', '20', '%', 'WSW 13 mph ', '75', '%', 
 'Mon', 'APR 29', 'Sunny', '62', '48', '10', '%', 'WNW 14 mph ', '63', '%', 
 'Tue', 'APR 30', 'Sunny', '61', '49', '0', '%', 'WNW 14 mph ', '61', '%', 
 'Wed', 'MAY 1', 'Mostly Sunny', '64', '50', '0', '%', 'WNW 12 mph ', '60', '%', 
 'Thu', 'MAY 2', 'Mostly Sunny', '65', '50', '0', '%', 'WNW 12 mph ', '61', '%', 
 'Fri', 'MAY 3', 'Mostly Sunny', '66', '51', '0', '%', 'WNW 13 mph ', '61', '%', 
 'Sat', 'MAY 4', 'Sunny', '65', '51', '0', '%', 'WNW 14 mph ', '62', '%', 
 'Sun', 'MAY 5', 'Sunny', '65', '51', '0', '%', 'WNW 14 mph ', '63', '%']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grab text like `Sunny. High 66F. Winds WNW at 5 to 10 mph.`, you can get them from the title attributes of `<td>`.

This should work.

```
td = table.xpath('.//tbody/tr/td[@class="description"]/@title')
```